# .htaccess redirect and change part of the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

```
http://www.example.com/amazing-car-wallpapers.html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/amazing-car-new-photos.html
```

so basically all the URLs that have `-wallpapers.html` to `-new-photos.html` (all the URLs that have `-wallpapers.html`).

`amazing-car` will always be a different term, and it will not have the same number of hyphens.

I did search online, but I couldn't find one that has the answer for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-wallpapers\.html$ $1-new-photos.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

This will match anything that ends with `-wallpapers.html` and redirect it to the same thing but with `-new-photos.html` instead.

Comment: You should add the R-flag. After the redirects have been tested the R flag should be replaced with `R=301`.

Comment: thanks, but it is not working. nothing happens. and I'm not sure I understand how to add the R flag

Comment: Order matters. This "redirect" directive will need to go near the start of the `.htaccess` file, before other rewrites. You will also need to add a slash prefix to the _substitution_ string, otherwise this will likely result in a malformed redirect (unless `RewriteBase` has been defined). ie. `/$1-new-photos.html`.